# The type toolkit:BusyIndicator was not found

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, wpftoolkit, busyindicator

I'm working on a WPF project with the beginning of a UserControl defined as:

```
<UserControl x:Class=""
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:.Modules.Converters"
         xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit/extended"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
```

Within the user control I have this:

```
<toolkit:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}" BusyContent="Please wait...">
```

I have the WPFToolkit.Extended referenced within my project and that reference appears to be valid (does not have a red underline).

However, I'm getting this error and don't know why:

The type 'toolkit:BusyIndicator' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the header of your XAML - just the `UserControl` definition.

Comment: Sorry about that! Forgot to use the StackOverflow code blocks when putting my comment in. I removed the class name and some of the converter definition, but that shouldn't be related. Thanks!

Comment: Have you added the reference in the project as well as the code?

Comment: Yes, the DLL is listed in the References folder as well as the above reference in the XAML. There's also a reference to "using Microsoft.Windows.Controls;" in the code behind page, but I'm not sure that it's necessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Navigate to the folder that conatins the DLL.  Right click on the DLL and select properties. Under the general tab near the bottom click the "Unblock" button. You should be good to go.

Comment: i'm in windows 7 i don't see an Unblock option in the properties context menu of the Dll file .

Comment: i can't see 'Unblock' option under the tab 'general'