# Can't find what assembly contains BusyIndicator

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0, busyindicator

I had my project written in Silverlight 4. Recently I've reinstalled my system and installed Silverlight 5. But when I re-installed "everything" I got the problem with BusyIndicator. It does look like this control was removed from System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit and attempts to compile my project (targeted still to Silverlight 4) fails with error:

**The type 'ToolkitControls:BusyIndicator' was not found.**

The namespace is defined as follow:

```
xmlns:ToolkitControls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;
      assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit"
```

I saw a lot of other topics on StackOverflow and see people use this control widely. That sounds like I don't have some toolbox installed or miss any assembly.

I do have the following components installed:

- MS VS 2010 SP1
- Tools for Visual Studio® 2010 SP1 ( http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28358)
- Silverlight 5 Toolkit - December 2011 ( http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/78435)

**Do I need something else?**

**Probably I need to add some reference to my project to have already installed toolboxes linked to my project?**

Please advise, any help is very much appreciated!

P.S. Recently found similar problem and solution for WPF ( [The type toolkit:BusyIndicator was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387163/the-type-toolkitbusyindicator-was-not-found)). But in my case I don't know with which assembly to start... I've looked through the GAC and "Program Files\Microsoft Silverlight": can't find any assemblies in that looks like related to Silverlight control toolbox...

Comment: Did you look under ToolBox--> Choose Items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heh, the answer was easy though not really obvious:

I should install toolkit for the 4th Silverlight (http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/43528)! :)

Answer (score 4):

I just added the same Tools and Silverlight 5 ToolKit to my Visual Studio installation. I was able to find the BusyIndicator by going to the ToolBox right clicking and then selectin ChooseItems I found it there not enabled.

> Namespace = System.Windows.Controls
>   Assembly Name = System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit
>   Directory = C:\Program files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Toolkit\dec11\Bin

[image]

Comment: Thank you for help, that really works for Silverlight 5 project. That also gave me motivation to keep finding the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I instaled nuget package and now working right.

```
PM> Install-Package SilverlightToolkit-All
```